# Volley BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 301

Tags: java, android, rest, android-volley

Hello I am having a problem. I am using Volley to request to https://swapi.dev/

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
     "http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
     System.out::println,
     null);
queue.add(request);
```

Then Volley throws an exception:

```
E/Volley: [53530] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 301 for http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/
```

Please help

Comment: Use in url "https://..." doesn't work

Comment: You are requesting `http://swapi.dev...` and the webserver at that address is returing a 301. This is a response indicating that the website has moved to `https://swapi.dev`. Changing the URL string in line 3 of your example to start with `https` rather than `http` will fix this issue. I've just done this in my browser, and can confirm that it works. Can you share some any error messages you receive when using https?

Answer (score -1):

You are using this url:

```
http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/
```

Enable "ClearText" compatibility to allow connections using `http:` , this must be done inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
   <application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Is recommended to use only `https://` like   `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/`